# Is every 3D Lie group with bi-invariant metric a space form?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I seem to remember to have read somewhere that, "in dimension three, every bi-invariant metric on a Lie group has constant curvature". However, I am not able to find a confirmation of this in any reference I know.

Can anybody please confirm/disprove such statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in Milnor's paper

*Curvatures of Left Invariant Metrics on Lie Groups*.

A connected Lie group G admits a bi-invariant metric if
and only if is isomorphic to the Cartesian product of a compact group and a vector space $\Bbb R^m$. In this case, it is a symmetric space. In dimension $3$, there are not so many possibilities and we can check this directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have just found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887338/christoffel-symbols-of-bi-invariant-metric-on-so3/1894667#1894667), which shows that the
Riemann curvature tensor of $SO(3)$ (with the bi-invariant metric) is not constant at a point. This seems to contradict the statement. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add the link of your statement about constant curvature?

Comment: @MK7:  The answer you link to exactly proves that $SO(3)$ with bi-invariant metric does have constant curvature.

Comment: @JasonDeVito It has indeed "constant (sectional) curvature", in the sense that the curvature does not depend on the point. Yet, at any given point, the curvature does depend on the tangent 2-plane. Do you agree?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have no link, sorry. In fact, I cannot even recall whether I read it online or not.

Comment: The  definition of constant curvature of a Lie group you want to use would be helpful then. Also the context. Are you interested in locally symmetric spaces?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, it is a problem of definitions. I must have read that such Lie groups have "constant curvature" and concluded automatically that "they are space forms" -- a conclusion that I could not digest. Evidently, they are not space forms, for the sectional curvature at any point does depend on the choice of tangent 2-plane. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @DietrichBurde And to answer your question, I am mainly interested in Riemannian submanifolds.

Comment: @MK7:  I disagree.  The curvature of any two-plane at any point is $1/4$, as shown in that answer.  Everywhere I have seen "constant curvature" used, it has meant "(sectional) curvature is indepenent of the point, and the two-plane at the point".  In this sense, $SO(3)$ with a bi-invariant metric has constant curvature.  Also, with this notion of "constant curvature", the conclusion that such a manifold is a space form is correct (using the fact that a bi-invariant metric on a non-abelian compact Lie group always has some positive curvatures.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you for the explanation, I see it now.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Are you by any chance aware of any proof that does not rely on checking each three-dimensional Lie group separately?

Comment: It is not "each" three-dimensional one. Only the compact ones, and direct products with abelian ones. How many compact (connected) Lie groups do we have in dimension $n\le 3$?

Comment: Yes, sure, but still it would be nice to have a general proof, I believe

Comment: It is known that the bi-invariant metric on any compact *simple* Lie group has constant Ricci curvature. Hence one can argue directly that, in dimension three, all such Lie groups have constant curvature.

Comment: In dimension three this is just $SO(3)$, so we are not gaining much. Either way is clear and has been written down (you wanted a reference, and we have several ones now).