# Lie group with constant metric tensor but nonzero curvature?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups

For any Lie group $\mathcal{G}$, if an inner-product is defined on the tangent space at the identity element $I$, then an inner-product can be induced on the tangent space at any other point $x$ by left-invariance:
$$
\big{\langle} u\ \big{|}\ v \big{\rangle}_x := \big{\langle} dL_x^{-1}(u)\ \big{|}\ dL_x^{-1}(v) \big{\rangle}_I
$$

where $\langle u\ |\ v\rangle_x$ is the inner-product of any $u,v \in T_x(\mathcal{G})$ and $dL_x$ is the differential of the left group operator $L_x(y) = xy\ \ \forall x,y \in \mathcal{G}$. The resulting collection of inner-products constitute a metric tensor on $\mathcal{G}$, turning it into a Riemannian manifold. (The same mechanism can be applied using the right group operator but I think I only need to address one of the two).

If $\mathcal{G}=\text{SO(3)}$, then $dL_x^{-1}=X^\intercal$ where $X$ is an orthogonal matrix with determinant 1. Thus the left-invariant metric tensor is,
\begin{align}
\big{\langle} u\ \big{|}\ v \big{\rangle}_x &= \big{\langle} X^\intercal u\ \big{|}\ X^\intercal v \big{\rangle}_I\\[6pt]
&= \big{\langle} u\ \big{|}\ XX^\intercal v \big{\rangle}_I\\[6pt]
&= \big{\langle} u\ \big{|}\ v \big{\rangle}_I
\end{align}

This leaves me with three conflicting statements:

1. The left-invariant metric tensor on SO(3) is constant.
2. Any Riemannian manifold with a constant metric tensor (in at least one coordinate system) has zero curvature.
3. With the left-invariant metric tensor, SO(3) has nonzero curvature, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1894667/295791).

One or more of these must be false. What am I messing-up here?

I feel like #1 is a dubious assessment because surely a change of coordinates should affect that, and I don't see how coordinates even work in to the logic outlined above. Meanwhile #2 is something I've not seen proved, but only stated off-hand in numerous physics contexts. Finally, #3 seems correct but the proof is somewhat beyond my surface-level dive into the subject so far.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: This question is more for my benefit, but does the differential of that operator also equate to the generator of that group element $x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2. and 3. are both correct statements. More precisely, 2. says the following:

> if there is a local chart $(U ,(x^i))$ of a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ so that
> $$ g = \sum_{i,j} g_{ij} dx^i dx^j$$
> locally on $U$ for some constants matric $(g_{ij})$. then $g$ has zero curvature.

But 1. does not imply 2. The metric that you construct in 1. is called left-invariant and there is no local coordinates where you can write this metric as  a constant matrix.

This confusion is present in every Riemannian manifold. At every point, one can find a local orthogonal frame $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$: that is, $e_i$ are local vector fields on $U$ so that $g(e_i, e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. This can be found by (e.g.) gram schmidt process. This does not imply that $g$ has zero curvature.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this part: "... there are no local coordinates where you can write this metric as a constant matrix." I am confused because it seems that if we let $\langle \text{e}_i | \text{e}_j \rangle_I := \delta_{ij}$ at the identity then we have $\langle \text{e}_i  |\text{e}_j \rangle_x = \delta_{ij}$ everywhere, regardless of coordinates. How is that not constant? I appreciate your patience!

Comment: @jnez71 As I said, that you can find an orthonormal basis, even a global one, does not imply that it has zero curvatures. Having a local orthonormal frame is different from having a local coordinates so that $g$ is constant there. Your orthonormal frame might not come from coordinates vector fields. In terms of calculation, that makes a huge difference since coordinates vector fields has vanishing Lie bracket $[\partial_i, \partial_j ] =0$, while the lie bracket $[e_i, e_j]$ is in general not zero.

Comment: Doesn't this orthonormal frame come from $n$ left-invariant vector fields? (Corresponding to $n$ orthonormal vectors in the Lie algebra). Why can't we take those to be "coordinates vector fields?"

Comment: Ah wait, the reasoning goes the other way around. We can show that the left-invariant vector fields have $[\text{e}_i, \text{e}_j] \neq 0$ in general, and that's *why* we can't call them coordinate vector fields. Then, using $\{\text{e}_i\}$ affects the calculation of Riemann curvature, making it nonzero even if the coefficients expressing the metric tensor are the same everywhere?